# Combine material coefficients and textures in Phong Shading

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, phong, shading

I'm trying to implement a simple Phong shader that supports non-physically-based materials and textures. Even though the material has a texture for each light component I still want the respective material coefficient to have some effect. My doubt is how to handle both of them. Should I mix, multiply or sum them? Right now I've multiplied them:

```
ambient  = material.ambient_color  * light.ambient  * texture_ambient;
diffuse  = material.diffuse_color  * light.diffuse  * diffuse_strength  * texture_diffuse;
specular = material.specular_color * light.specular * specular_strength * texture_specular;
```

It seems kinda dark, is this the correct way to combine material coefficients and textures?

Comment: There is no right or wrong since it is not physically based. Choose whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This depends. In the end it's up to you to decide. If it's too dark, try something else.

You could just apply the material coefficent to your texture. I guess that's how it's done most of the time. But as BDL mentioned: This is not physically-based, so it's really up to you and there is no right or wrong.

That said: If you want to keep it separate, you could try to use high(er) material coefficients. If they only range from 0.9 to 1 they won't darken the object too much. If they range from 0 to 1 you could make use of `smoothstep(0.9, 1, material.coefficient)` or something like that.